# I need to conditionally format cells that include *,**,*** but excel reads those as all cells containing numbers

Tags: excel, formatting

Basically the title. I need to change the color of cells with +,*,**,***, but excel reads * as any cells containing a number

I tried adding '(ctrl+alt+p) before the symbol,and before and after the symbol ('*').
I tried adding it as *"~*", did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Use mix of `FIND` and `ISNUMBER`:

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("*",A1))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I couldnt make the =ISNUMBER(FIND("*",A1)) work, bu i endedn up solving this by formating the numbers to text, then adding rules to mark cells red if they end in *,** or ***